# CS50 Plurality using voters_count

Tags: c, cs50

I thought it would be really practical to use the `int voter_count` from the `main` function also in my `print_winners` function. But since the `int voter_count` is not introduced before the `main` function as the i`nt candidates_count` is, for example, I am not able to use the `voter_count int`.

When I introduce the `int` before `main` and remove the `int` before `voters_count` in the `main` function when it is getting called, then my code works and all scenarios I tried worked correctly.

But I know that we were not supposed to change code in the `main` function and even with the changed `main` function my code still does not pass the check50.

Does anyone know why my code is not passing the check50?

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    for (int c = voter_count; (c > 0); c--)
    {
        int u = 0;

        for (int j = 0; (j < candidate_count); j++)
        {
            if (candidates[j].votes == c)
            {
                u++;
                printf("%s \n", candidates[j].name);
            }
        }

        if (u != 0)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Response for check:

[image: response for check]

```
    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
```

Here I changed the `main` function by removing the `int` before the `voter_count` because

```
//Numver of votes
int voter_count;
```

I introduce the program to the `int` above the header file.

Comment: That's a terrible way to determine the candidate(s) that received the maximum number of votes... Simply make one pass over the candidates to find the maximum value, then another pass to print the one (or several) that achieved the maximum... You don't need "voter_count" in this function...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now also figured that going through all possible votes is not the best way to determine the winner. Ans the  problem with check50 not approving my code was because of the space between %s and \n in the printf function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in C can use either global variables (but please *don't*), local variables, or their arguments. A local variable in one function cannot be accessed in another.

E.g.

```
void foo(void);

int main(void) {
  int bar = 42;

  foo();

  return 0;
}

void foo(void) {
  printf("%d\n", bar);
}
```

That will not work. However, we can pass `bar` as an argument to `foo`.

```
void foo(int bar);

int main(void) {
  int bar = 42;

  foo(bar);

  return 0;
}

void foo(int bar) {
  printf("%d\n", bar);
}
```

The following will work, but you *shouldn't* use it.

```
int bar;

void foo(void);

int main(void) {
  bar = 42;

  foo();

  return 0;
}

void foo(void) {
  printf("%d\n", bar);
}
```